# Pivoting Column has N/A in DataFrame which Python is filtering

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to pivot columns in CSV. I am first pulling them into a dataframe and pivoting them. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df1=pd.read_csv("C:\\testfolder\\testdemofinal1.csv",sep=',')

df=pd.DataFrame(df1)

a=df.pivot_table(index='Parameter1_Calculation',columns='Measure Names', values='Measure Values',aggfunc='first')

b=a.to_csv("C:\\newfile1.csv",sep=',')
```

But here in the output pandas is filtering out the row which has N/A. I tried out this but still it has not solved my issue:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df1=pd.read_csv("C:\\testfolder\\testdemofinal1.csv",sep=',')

df=pd.DataFrame(df1)

df=df.replace({'N/A':'No Data'},regex=True)

a=df.pivot_table(index='Parameter1_Calculation',columns='Measure Names', values='Measure Values',aggfunc='first',dropna=True,margins_name='All')

b=a.to_csv("C:\\newfile1.csv",sep=',').
```

N/A has values against it which I need and dont want to be filtered out. I have attached how it looks in csv:
[This is how it looks. I am trying to pivot cols: param1 and param2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnhE6.png)

Thanks in advance.

I have attached the snippet of csv file below:
[Snippet of Csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3QS.png)

Comment: Post a sample of your csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `na_filter =False`  while using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) . This should help you to get away with the problem.

> na_filter : boolean, default True
>   Detect missing value markers (empty strings and the value of na_values). In data without any NAs, passing na_filter=False can improve the performance of reading a large file

Comment: Thanks for the answer.